# Find the minimum value of $\sin^4 x + \frac{3}{2} \cos^4 x,$ as $x$ varies over all real numbers.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum value of
$\sin^4 x + \frac{3}{2} \cos^4 x,$ as $x$ varies over all real numbers.

I'm not even sure how to start on this problem. Could someone please help?

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: Let $\sin^2\theta=t$ where $0\leq t\leq 1$, then use the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, You'd be able to proceed from there.

Comment: Let $u=\cos x$ and $v=\sin x$. Then as $x$ varies over $\mathbb{R}$, the pair $(u,v)$ varies over the unit circle $u^2+v^2=1$. This means that your problem is equivalent to minimising $u^4+\dfrac{3}{4}v^4$ subject to $u^2+v^2=1$. This can be solved without much difficulty using Lagrange multipliers. (Leaving as a comment instead of an answer because this probably isn't what you were looking for.)

Comment: @730563 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y=2\cos^2y-1$

$$8f=2(1-\cos2y)^2+3(1+\cos2y)^2$$

$$40f=25+(5\cos2y+1)^2-1$$

Now for real $y,$ $$-1\le\cos2y\le1$$

$$\implies-5+1\le5\cos2y+1\le5+1$$

$$\implies0\le(5\cos2y+1)^2\le6^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We can write your expression in function of $\sin(x)$, so:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sin^4(x)+\frac{3}{2}$$
Let $t=\sin^2(x)$, we arrive at:
$$f(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}(5t^2-6t+3)$$
This is just a parabola with centre on the $y-$axis and $0\leq t\leq 1$. In this interval the maximum point is reached when:
$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{3}{5} \rightarrow \sin^4(x)=\frac{9}{25} \land \cos^4(x)=\frac{4}{25} $$
So, the maximum value reached is:
$$M=\frac{9}{25}+\dfrac{3}2\cdot\frac{4}{25}=\frac{15}{25}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: @730563: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: Instead of posting my own answer, I'd like to offer you a chance to edit yours. The substitution is valid, but the equation you should've gotten is: $\dfrac{1}{2}(5t^2-6t+3)$. Which leads to a minimum occuring when $\sin^2 x=0.6$

Comment: @Plato: yes, corrected. Sorry.

Comment: Um, $\cos^2 x=1-\dfrac{3}{5}$

Comment: @Plato: yeah, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $y=\sin^4 x + \frac{3}{2} \cos^4 x,$

So $dy/dx=4\sin^3x\cos x+\frac{3}{2} 4\cos^3x(-\sin x)$$=4\sin x\cos x(\sin^2x-\frac{3}{2} \cos^2x)=4\sin x\cos x(1-\frac{5}{2} \cos^2x)$

Therefore $dy/dx=0$  when $\cos x=0$ or  $\sin x=0$ or $\cos^2 x=2/5$  and $\sin^2 x=3/5. $  Substitute these cases in $y$ to decide the minimum.